# Google Maps - Map Not Loaded

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to create a map and load .kmz file using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> <meta charset="utf-8">
<style type ="text/css"> html, body, #map-canvas { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px}</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=visualization&key=mykey"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(58.33, -98.52),
      zoom: 11,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var kmzLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('link_to_kmz_file');
    kmzLayer.setMap(map);
  }
</script>

</head
<body>
<div id="map_canvas"> </div>
</body
</html>
```

The problem comes up when nothing is loaded and I have no idea why it happens. I should mention my `API_KEY` is valid, since I use it for creating another maps that does not require .kmz file loading, and I also do not store the .kmz file on localhost but on my own server.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could point me to the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you see successful request\response to the KML in your brwser debugging tools?

Comment: Where do you call  `initialize()`?

Comment: What is the [status of the KmlLayer](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayerStatus)? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you aren't calling `initialize()` anywhere, just declaring it. Add it to the body onload if you want to call it when body loaded.

```
<body onload="initialize()">
```

also your closing body tag is incomplete

```
</body>
```

and your closing head tag

```
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the map is not loaded again.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, you are using:

```
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

and in your CSS:

```
#map-canvas {
    ...
}
```

**Issue**: `map-canvas` ≠ `map_canvas`

Since the map needs a height to be displayed, your map won't show until you correct your CSS like hereafter:

```
#map_canvas {
    ...
}
```

---

**+** You need to correct your closing `</head>` and `</body>` tags.

---

**+** You need to call the `initialize()` function.

Add this to your javascript:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0):

add after your function like this

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(58.33, -98.52),
      zoom: 11,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var kmzLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('link_to_kmz_file');
    kmzLayer.setMap(map);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>`
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this
`google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`

Comment: This looks like it may be the solution - I would be a better answer if it explains to the original poster why this would make it work, or where they should add this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the map is not loaded again.